# Having an issue inserting values into an array at an index given by my hash function

Tags: c++, arrays

I am getting memory locations when I attempt to print out given indexes of arrays that are being "filled" by two hash functions.
when I print out x or y to the console I get valid integers within the size of the array, however it does not appear that the array is actually being affected when i try to add 1 to the array at x or y (horner[x] or myH[y]). I am unsure how to progress forward

```
int main() {
    int *horn;
    int *myH;
    int size;
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    char choice;
    int hc, mc, maxH, maxM;
    string key;

    fstream inFile;
    inFile.open("words.txt");

    do {
        cout << "Enter number of words to be hashed";
        cin >> size;

        horn = new int[size];
        myH = new int[size];

            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                inFile >> key;

                x = hashHorner(key, size);
                y = myHash(key, size);


                horn[x] += 1;
                myH[y] += 1;
            }

        hc = numCollisions(horn, size);
        mc = numCollisions(myH, size);
        maxH = maxCollisions(horn, size);
        maxM = maxCollisions(myH, size);

        cout << horn[5];
        cout << myH[10];

        cout << "\nhashHorner num collisions: " << hc;
        cout << "\nmyHash num collisions: " << mc;
        cout << "\nhashHorner max collisions: " << maxH;
        cout << "\nmyHash max collisions: " << maxM;

        cout << "\nWould you like to continue hashing?";
        cin >> choice;

    } while (choice != 'n');

    inFile.close();
}


int hashHorner(const string& key, int size) {
    unsigned int hashVal = 0;

    for (char ch : key)
        hashVal = 37 * hashVal + ch;

    return (int)(hashVal % size);
}


int myHash(const string& key, int size) {
    unsigned int hashVal = 0;

    for (char ch : key)
        hashVal = 3301 * hashVal + ch;

    return (int)(hashVal % size);
}

int numCollisions(int array[], int size) {
    int n = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (array[i] > 1) n++;
    }
    return n;
}

int maxCollisions(int array[], int size) {
    int max = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (array[i] > max) max = array[i];
    }
    return max;
}
```